# How do I fix a greyed-out dual monitor on a machine with NVidia graphics?

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors

I have a dual monitor on my fresh Ubuntu 11.10 install. The problem is that it works for a very short time, then the second monitor turns grey.

My videocard is a GeForce 210 1GB DDR3 and the nvidia-current drivers are activated.

Comment: check under the icon of the gear, in the upper right corner, there is a shortcut for the display management, try to set your displays from there.

Comment: @Micro when opening the Ubuntu displays manager then only one display is recognized. Though, in the Nividiap-setting i have two displays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open the `NVIDIA X Server Settings` application. This was installed with your NVidia proprietary drivers.
2. Navigate to the "X Server Display Configuration" screen.
3. In the "Display" tab, select the greyed-out monitor with the "Model" selector.
4. Set the "Configuration" option of that monitor to "TwinView" mode.
5. Restart your computer.

Answer (score 0):

After such a struggle with settings here and settings this I clicked on dash, typed in driver selected additional driver. Here you should see that you 2 options after clicking on it.

1. NVIDIA accelerated graphics dirver (version current)[Recommended]
2. NVIDIA accelerated graphics dirver (post-release updates)(version current-updates)

I had 1 selected as this is how I installed my driver initially. This then broke and after a struggle as mentioned above I selected 2 and clicked on activate, restarted my machine and boom. Up and working np. Here is my xorg.conf file [paste bin entry](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1039200/)

Comment: on 22.04 switching it to an older one then back again worked for me. at first I didn't suspect drivers because there were several other symptoms : everything but the focused window was locked and even the focused window couldn't be clicked a dragged most of the time also you can see the taskbar (dash-to-panel) and the full screen start menu, on the grey screen. but yeah switching it to old driver rebbot, switching back and reboot again worked.